# Check if contact already present in abaddressbook

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I have a app which takes backup for contacts. All records are sent to server in `NSData` format.
Also I have put restore functionality. Issue is duplicate record is created in phone contact.
I wanted to compare `ABrecordId`. But when I restore and get vcard, its `ABRecordId` is -1.
How can I solve this. Please help.